# IE Form Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a problem with Internet Explorer. I have to use the attribute Form, the problem is that it doesn't work on Internet Explorer (compatibility problem). How could I do this on jQuery?

```
<button type="submit" id="cancelForm" name="cancel" onclick="bCancel=true" form="myForm"/>
```

---

I've tryed with this code

```
$("#cancelForm").click(function() {
    bCancel = true;
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

I am trying to emulate the form attribute and the bCancel functionality. When I press the cancel button, it submits the form, but when it checks for the bCancel variable, it returns other value.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is exactly not working? Please update your question and try to be more clear about the problem you are facing. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer, I don't know what else I can say...

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez What value does it return?

Comment: A little OT, what does `bCancel = true;` do?

Comment: Sets the variable bCancel to true, so the Struts Validator will pass control through to the Action.

Comment: Both of the code snippets you've provided should successfully post the form (and indeed you confirm that they do), so there's nothing wrong there; certainly no browser compatibility in the way you're thinking it is. We probably need to see more about what you're doing with `bCancel`; that's where the issue lies. The fact that it's a global variable suggests that there might be a timing issue or an event sequence issue, or something like that, but I can't be more specific without seeing a whole lot more code.